# Cell title containing formula for transposed data in row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a DATA sheet where data is stored in columns:

[image]

On my OUTPUT sheet, I can display this data with a title cell with no issues, provided I continue to do so vertically with this formula in Cell A1 - `={"COLUMN 1";DATA!A2:A}`:

[image]

My issue is when I try to do this horizontally with this formula - `={"ROW 1";ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(DATA!A2:A))}` I get this error - *'In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.'*

What do I need to do in order to display the data from the columns on the DATA sheet displayed horizontally on the OUTPUT sheet with a title in Cell D1 and the corresponding data following it in the rest of the row?

[image]

See my example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HDCG_21vCtrLO3cuAR3kS-2kMAq1ch3azUMXtp6a6B8/edit#gid=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with:

```
={"ROW 1",TRANSPOSE(DATA!A2:A)}
```

OR

```
={"ROW 1",TOROW(DATA!A2:A)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
={"ROW 1",TRANSPOSE(DATA!A2:A)}
```

Comment: Really, a comma instead of a semicolon? Lol, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single formula for both rows

```
={{"ROW 1:";"ROW 2:"},TRANSPOSE(A2:B)}
```